# Exported functions in newer version of bash does not work anymore (with sed e flag)

Tags: bash, sed

I'm seeing weird behavior of bash exported functions with e flag of sed substitution command.

Old scripts I have is using this functionality for passing parameters to command inside 
sed search/replace. However this does not seem to work anymore on newer versions of bash.

I've tested this on my old Windows box with cygwin and bash 4.1.16(8) and have expected behavior:

```
$ func() { echo $1 123; } ; export -f func ; echo test | sed 's/.*/func \0/ge'
test 123
```

However on linux with newer version of bash 4.3.11(1) this does not work:

```
$ func() { echo $1 123; } ; export -f func ; echo test | sed 's/.*/func \0/ge'
sh: 1: func: not found
```

Both PCs have sed version 4.2.2.

Question is - am I missing something or new versions of bash (after Shellshock) broke this functionality (exporting functions)? Also if this is broken then how can I move my old scripts from Windows/cygwin and still have them working? - and yes I know I can rewrite them with some changes.

Comment: Is `/bin/sh` bash on your Linux machine?

Comment: this more a quote/double quote problem than an export. Sed take it litteraly in your single quoted action list. This is more a bug (or limited implementation due to windows constraint) in win/cygwin bash than in linux one.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: there's no quoting issue here. Notice the `/e` (GNU I think) "modifier" in the sed expression.

Comment: @mat: you are right, i forget the `/e` that i never use on AIX. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it turns out to be another problem with **dash** being default **/bin/sh**

Thanks to Cyrus for hint with bash -c (and actually I think that it's another point for ALWAYS directly specifying which shell use for doing work you want to be really done)

In meanwhile I've tested older version of ubuntu livecd - and the problem persisted. So it's not fault of shellshock fix. Moreover I've seen different behavior while doing:

```
... | sed 's/.*/sh -c "func" \0/ge'
```

than proposed:

```
... | sed 's/.*/bash -c "func" \0/ge'
```

And it looks that this happens only with dash as default shell - go figure.

So the answer is:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

After this everything works like expected.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

```
func() { echo $1 123; } ; export -f func ; echo test | sed 's/.*/bash -c "func" \0/ge'
```

Output:

```
123
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint. And for idea to have better portability of this kind of scripts - directly pointing out to use bash than default shell surely should work better than relying on unknown system setup.